# Multicast in private LAN with different subnets

Tags: networking, routing, subnet, udp, multicast

after i read

[Multicast IP Addresses](https://serverfault.com/questions/258237/multicast-ip-addresses)

and

[Multicast accross the subnets](https://serverfault.com/questions/146457/multicast-accross-the-subnets)

I am confused.
Configuration: I have two devices in the same network. They may not be in the same Subnet, but always in the same physical network (beyond the same router or switch etc.)

I want to communicate across IP multicast either 224.x.x.x or 239.x.x.x may be more fitting because we want it local, **not** beyond or forward through the router.

Can one machine be the receiver and the other machine sender of the same multicast address?
and
can the receiving machine send an answer to the sending machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both machines (or any other multicast capable device) can be a sender, a receiver or both.  So, yes, assuming the protocol is appropriate your receiving machine can use the same multicast group to respond to the source.